# No DKIM headers in sent mails from postfix

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, sendmail, dkim, ubuntu-20.04

I have two postfix, one for receiving mails and the other for sending mails, and I am having trouble signing dkim on my outgoing mails. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/postfix-send-only-multiple-domains-ubuntu).

Logs also is not helping me point to the main problem. OpenDKIM is running fine:

```
● opendkim.service - OpenDKIM DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/opendkim.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-06-18 17:39:40 UTC; 4s ago
       Docs: man:opendkim(8)
             man:opendkim.conf(5)
             man:opendkim-genkey(8)
             man:opendkim-genzone(8)
             man:opendkim-testadsp(8)
             man:opendkim-testkey
             http://www.opendkim.org/docs.html
    Process: 246310 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 246321 (opendkim)
      Tasks: 7 (limit: 4681)
     Memory: 2.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/opendkim.service
             ├─246321 /usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf
             └─246322 /usr/sbin/opendkim -x /etc/opendkim.conf

Jun 18 17:39:40 testmailcdo systemd[1]: Starting OpenDKIM DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter...
Jun 18 17:39:40 testmailcdo systemd[1]: Started OpenDKIM DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter.
Jun 18 17:39:40 testmailcdo opendkim[246322]: OpenDKIM Filter v2.11.0 starting (args: -x /etc/opendkim.conf)
```

My postfix main.cf:

```
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
#smtpd_milters = inet:localhost:8891
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters =  $smtpd_milters
```

master.cf:

```
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=may
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=no
#  -o smtpd_tls_auth_only=yes
  -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
#  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=$smtpauth_recipient_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options=noanonymous
```

opendkim.conf:

```
# This is a basic configuration that can easily be adapted to suit a standard
# installation. For more advanced options, see opendkim.conf(5) and/or
# /usr/share/doc/opendkim/examples/opendkim.conf.sample.

# Log to syslog
Syslog                  yes
# Required to use local socket with MTAs that access the socket as a non-
# privileged user (e.g. Postfix)
UMask                   007

# Sign for example.com with key in /etc/dkimkeys/dkim.key using
# selector '2007' (e.g. 2007._domainkey.example.com)
#Domain                 testmailcdo.apolloglobal.net
#KeyFile                /etc/dkimkeys/dkim.key
#Selector               mail1

# Commonly-used options; the commented-out versions show the defaults.
Canonicalization        relaxed/relaxed
Mode                    sv
SubDomains              no

AutoRestart         yes
AutoRestartRate     10/1M
Background          yes
DNSTimeout          5
SignatureAlgorithm  rsa-sha256

# Socket smtp://localhost
#
# ##  Socket socketspec
# ##
# ##  Names the socket where this filter should listen for milter connections
# ##
# ##  Names the socket where this filter should listen for milter connections
# ##  from the MTA.  Required.  Should be in one of these forms:
# ##
# ##  inet:port@address           to listen on a specific interface
# ##  inet:port                   to listen on all interfaces
# ##  local:/path/to/socket       to listen on a UNIX domain socket
#
#Socket                  inet:8891@localhost
#Socket                 local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock
#Socket local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock
Socket local:/var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock
##  PidFile filename
###      default (none)
###
###  Name of the file where the filter should write its pid before beginning
###  normal operations.
#
PidFile               /var/run/opendkim/opendkim.pid


# Always oversign From (sign using actual From and a null From to prevent
# malicious signatures header fields (From and/or others) between the signer
# and the verifier.  From is oversigned by default in the Debian pacakge
# because it is often the identity key used by reputation systems and thus
# somewhat security sensitive.
OversignHeaders         From

##  ResolverConfiguration filename
##      default (none)
##
##  Specifies a configuration file to be passed to the Unbound library that
##
##  Specifies a configuration file to be passed to the Unbound library that
##  performs DNS queries applying the DNSSEC protocol.  See the Unbound
##  documentation at http://unbound.net for the expected content of this file.
##  The results of using this and the TrustAnchorFile setting at the same
##  time are undefined.
##  In Debian, /etc/unbound/unbound.conf is shipped as part of the Suggested
##  unbound package

# ResolverConfiguration     /etc/unbound/unbound.conf

##  TrustAnchorFile filename
##      default (none)
##
## Specifies a file from which trust anchor data should be read when doing
## DNS queries and applying the DNSSEC protocol.  See the Unbound documentation
## at http://unbound.net for the expected format of this file.

TrustAnchorFile       /usr/share/dns/root.key

##  Userid userid
###      default (none)
###
###  Change to user "userid" before starting normal operation?  May include
###  a group ID as well, separated from the userid by a colon.
#
UserID                opendkim
# Map domains in From addresses to keys used to sign messages
KeyTable           refile:/etc/opendkim/key.table
SigningTable       refile:/etc/opendkim/signing.table

# Hosts to ignore when verifying signatures
ExternalIgnoreList  /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts

# A set of internal hosts whose mail should be signed
InternalHosts       /etc/opendkim/trusted.hosts
```

Logs when sending mail affect by `trusted.hosts`

```
Jun 18 18:14:08 testmailcdo postfix/submission/smtpd[247218]: connect from unknown[202.60.9.10]
Jun 18 18:14:08 testmailcdo postfix/submission/smtpd[247218]: 6D0D413C124: client=unknown[202.60.9.10]
Jun 18 18:14:08 testmailcdo postfix/cleanup[247221]: 6D0D413C124: message-id=<4beaf35a08d40fa7f8f746ab309b8436@poultrymax.com>
Jun 18 18:14:08 testmailcdo postfix/qmgr[246787]: 6D0D413C124: from=<testmenard@poultrymax.com>, size=601, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 18 18:14:08 testmailcdo postfix/submission/smtpd[247218]: disconnect from unknown[202.60.9.10] ehlo=1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 quit=1 commands=5
Jun 18 18:14:10 testmailcdo postfix/smtp[247222]: 6D0D413C124: to=<potapo183@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.157.26]:25, delay=1.8, delays=0.06/0/0.82/0.97, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1624040055 p7si10315751pjl.99 - gsmtp)
Jun 18 18:14:10 testmailcdo postfix/qmgr[246787]: 6D0D413C124: removed
```

`ls -l /var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock` outputs:

```
srwxrwx--- 1 opendkim opendkim 0 Jun 18 17:39 /var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

I am really lost. Any suggestions and help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Reconsider `milter_default_action` - you might not actually want this to *fail-open* (`accept`) but instead have all problems with DKIM be promoted to grinding everything to a halt (`tempfail`, which may be the safer choice in terms of losing mail, because of what some recipients do with mail they consider unauthorized).

Comment: @anx logs while processing mail affected by `trusted.hosts` does not show something about calling the milter. Either way, I have updated the post with logs from postfix while sending a mail.

Comment: Could it be "outgoing" mail is processed by another `smtpd` service which has milter disabled (e.g. `submission`? Check `master.cf`. Also, I noticed some time ago that opendkim set modes on the socket so the postfix was unable to communicate with it. It must have been fixed since, but who knows...

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -l /var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock` to the question? I suspect your socket only allows opendkim:opendkim while postfix runs as another user.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I have added my `master.cf` on the question. I believe it is handled by `submission`

Comment: @Ginnungagap I added the output of `ls -l /var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock`. I am not very familiar with linux but shouldn't `sudo chown opendkim:postfix /var/spool/postfix/opendkim`, as a step in the guide, would fix the permission problem?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Is there a way to make `submission` use the opendkim milter?

Comment: According to your master.cf, the Postfix submission should use smtpd milters too. Wrong modes (0770 for opendkim:opendkim) must be a culprit.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrong modes on the `opendkim.sock`. Those are `0770` i.e. `rwx` by owner, `rwx` by group, nothing for others, where owner is `opendkim` and group is `opendkim`, but Postfix runs often as `postfix:mail` or something like that, so it falls into the category "others" and is disallowed access. You should find mentions of that in the Postfix logs (in Debian we look into `/var/log/mail.err`).

Also note, the `chown` you've done was acting on a *directory, containing the socket*, not the socket itself, so it doesn't suffice.

Try setting `0777` on the `opendkim.sock` as the one-time test solution:

```
chmod 0777 /var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock
```

If it helps, we're on the right track. OpenDKIM recreates the socket with former modes at each restart, so the modes will reset, that's why this solution is one time. To make it persistent, add `postfix` user (or whichever account the `smtpd` is running under) into `opendkim` group, so the second "7" will apply to it (group access which is allowed):

```
gpasswd -a postfix opendkim
```

Alternatively (for example, if `smtpd` runs under `nobody`), you might change startup script for OpenDKIM slightly, for it to set mode `0777` after socket creation.

Comment: I appreciate your help sir, but unfortunately after running `chmod 0777 /var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock` and making the opendkim.sock to `srwxrwxrwx 1 opendkim opendkim 0 Jun 19 14:21 /var/spool/postfix/opendkim/opendkim.sock` mails sent still does not have dkim on its headers. Also when I check `/var/log/mail.err`, it was blank.

Comment: Also, I tried using `inet` as socket pointed to localhost, altered postfix smtpd milters  and non smtpd milters to use `inet:localhost:8891` but it does not help. Mails still are not signed.